# Unable to click on WebElement in a list within a list

Tags: java, reactjs, selenium

I have a list of WebElements which I intend to filter using streams(), then match each element to a string and lastly click on the element. So far I've not been able to debug this minor issue, and could use the help of briliant minds from the StackOverflow community.

My page object class consists of the following:

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "ul.container-content > li:nth-of-type(1) > ul > li > a")
private List<WebElement> lnkMenuItems;

private WebElement getElementFromList(List<WebElement> elements, String title) {
    return elements.stream()
            .filter(element -> element.getText().contains(title))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(null);
}

public void clickOnMenuItem(String title) {
    btnMegaMenu.click();
    WebElement lnkMenuItem = getElementFromList(lnkMenuItems, title);
    // global wait method from my base page class utilizing fluentwait
    waitFor(lnkMenuItem);
    lnkMenuItem.click();
}
```

The menu app I'm trying to automate is coded using ReactJS, and here's a snippet of what I based my CSS selector on:

```
<div class="nav-menu  ">
<ul role="menu" class="container-content">
    <li>
        <a href="/betale" target="" role="menuitem" class=" header-hidden-mobile">Betaling og kort</a>
        <button class=" sub-menu-btn header-hidden-desktop" aria-label="Betaling og kort" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="defe4678-4bf6-4657-b677-ea732da4182c">Betaling og kort</button>
        <button class="mobile-menu-back" aria-label="Tilbake til hovedmeny">Betaling og kort</button>
        <ul id="defe4678-4bf6-4657-b677-ea732da4182c">
            <li>
                <a href="/betale" target="" class=" header-hidden-desktop" role="menuitem">
                    <span class="sr-only">Betaling og kort</span> Oversikt
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/spare" target="" class="" role="menuitem">QA Mega Menu Clone Test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/betale/bankid" target="" class="" role="menuitem">BankID p&#229; Mobil</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/betale/bankkort" target="" class="" role="menuitem">Bankkort</a>
            </li>
```

I'm targeting the URL dynamically (in this case the fourth `<li>`) based on the string passed in as an argument, but I just can't seem to click on the element. Is my CSS selector way off? Any other pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as though Selenium always was able to fire the click event on the menu item. I just needed a method to chain together the redirect and verify that the expected results matched my criteria. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from using wrong annotation at following code,  You hope find all matched elements as a List, you should use `@FindAll` or `@FindBys`, rather than `@FindBy` which return one element.

```
@FindAll({@FindBy(css = "ul.container-content > li:nth-of-type(1) > ul > li > a")})
private List<WebElement> lnkMenuItems;
```

Comment: Regardless of whether I use `@FindAll` or only `@FindBy` I still get the same results, a size of 12 menu items. However, Selenium still does not click on the item that I want it to click on but the test seems to pass for some reason.

Comment: I temporarily changed the click action with an `System.out.println(lnkMenuItem)` just to see what it prints out, and it doesn't seem to filter through the elements in order to get the element where the text contains the string.

Output
`[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (83b9616db542e5acbccdd66f6c81fdee)] -> css selector: ul.container-content > li:nth-of-type(1) > ul > li > a]`

Comment: Try add a long sleep after `btnMegaMenu.click();` for debug purpose to see whether we need to wait something loading.

Comment: I tried bumping up my wait wrapper to 10 secs, and adding a sleep as you suggested after the first click action. Still nothing. Could there be something wrong with my CSS selector?